# Can we automatically add Marshmallow shemas to swagger `api.doc()`?

Tags: python, api, flask, marshmallow

I have an API which I would like to display via Swagger UI. I do so by:

```
bp = Blueprint("api", __name__)
api = Api(bp)

@api.doc(
    description="Description, I want to add schema here",
    responses={200: "Success"},
)
def post(self):
    """ Appears in Title of Swagger
        Authorization: Bearer <auth-key>
    """
    return jsonify(200)
```

Lets say I have the followinig Schema:

```
class SomeSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.String(required=True)
```

Is there a way to display this schema automatically for swagger? For example I would like to fill in:

[image]

to have contain the fields automatically.

Comment: Hey, did you ever find an answer to your question here? I am guessing you are using Flask-RestPlus or Flask-Restx?

Comment: Jerome posted an answer, although I didn't think it was worth the implementation for my use case.

Answer (score 6):

This is exactly what [apispec](https://apispec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is made for. It is developed by the marshmallow team.

(You may also be interested in [webargs](https://webargs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to parse inputs with marshmallow. And [flask-smorest](https://flask-smorest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for an integration of apispec and webargs into a complete API framework.)

*Disclaimer: marshmallow/apispec/webargs/flask-smorest maintainer.*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid using [apispec](https://apispec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as I did, you can manually convert the marshmallow schema to a flask model and use it on the api.expect decorator.

```
from flask_restx import fields as flask_fields
from marshmallow import fields as marshmallow_fields

# Map your types conversion here
TYPE_MAPPING = {
    marshmallow_fields.String: flask_fields.String,
    marshmallow_fields.Number: flask_fields.Integer,
    marshmallow_fields.DateTime: flask_fields.DateTime,
}

def convert_schema_to_flask_model(schema):
    schema_fields = getattr(schema, "_declared_fields")
    converted_schema = {}

    for field in schema_fields:
        converted_schema[field] = TYPE_MAPPING[type(schema_fields[field])]

    return converted_schema
```

Comment: If I understand right, this only convert the type, but not the arguments of each type, say the `default=None, required=True` parts for `fields.String()` ?